# Breadcrumbs based on URL with links (PHP, HTML, Codeigniter)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm makeing dynamic bredcrumbs based on current url i have. My problem is, that i can't figure out how to generate right link and attach it to word, because of foreach loop. My code is realy messy, so i whould realy need a help. Hope you guys can help!

Tnx

Here is my code:

```
<?php
        $url = current_url();
        $home = "www.homepage.com";
        $sub_url = substr($url, strpos($url, $home));
        $segments = explode("/", $url);
        $parts = array_slice($segments, 3);
        $count = count($parts);
        $i = 0;
        ?>
       //Don't show breadcrumb on home page
    <?php if (current_url() !== base_url() && current_url() !== base_url() . "home") { ?>
            <div class="breadcrumbs">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><div class="home">Home</div></a>
                <div class="divider1"></div>
                <?php
                foreach ($parts as $row) {
                    $bread = ucfirst(str_replace("-", " ", str_replace("_", " ", $row)));
                    ?>
                    <div class="level1" style="margin-left: -6px ;">
                       <a href="#"><?php echo $bread." ". $i; ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ($i < $count - 1) { ?>
                        <div class="divider1"></div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>
            </div>
   <?php }  ?>
```

EDIT:
Right link means if you have url like
www.homepage.com/mens_where/mens_jackets/Jacket123

Output should be something like that if i don't consider echo-ing classes in upper code

```
<a href="www.homepage.com">home</a>
<a href="www.homepage.com/mens_wear">Mens Wear</a>
<a href="www.homepage.com/mens_wear/mens_jackets">Mens jackets</a>
<a href="www.homepage.com/mens_wear/mens_jackets/Jacket123">Jacket123</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by right link?

Comment: I have updated a question, so you can understand it better.

Comment: Just as a side note, it should be `Mens Wear`...

Comment: Side node: `parse_url()` might be useful for you in this, and you can do `str_replace(array('-', '_'), '', $row)` to shorten that line

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? Because I made a library for making Breadcrumbs with CI. BTW, why you want it to be "automatic" based on URL? If you are using CI, you have a method for each first URL segment, so you know where "you are". So, you could create the breadcrumb inside the methods. Well, that's just what I do.

Comment: CodeIgniter always surprises me with their solutions! Somehow i missed URI Class documentation! I will check that and i will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final solution!

```
 <?php if (current_url() !== base_url() && current_url() !== base_url() . "home") { ?>
            <div class="breadcrumbs">
                <?php
                $segments = $this->uri->segment_array();
                $last_segment = '';?>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><div class="home">Home</div></a>
                <div class="divider1"></div>
                <?php
                foreach ($segments as $segment) {
                    $last_segment .= '/' . $segment;
                    ?>
                 <div class="level1" style="margin-left: -6px ;">
                     <?php
                    echo '<a href="'.base_url() . substr($last_segment,1) . '">' .    ucfirst(str_replace('-', ' ', str_replace('_', ' ', $segment))) . '</a>';
                    ?>
                     </div>
                     <div class="divider1"></div>
                     <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using codeigniter, try something like this:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
<?php
$segments = $this->uri->segment_array();
$last_segment = '';
foreach ($segments as $segment) {
    $last_segment .= '/' . $segment;
    echo '<a href="www.homepage.com' . $last_segment . '">' . ucfirst(str_replace(array('-', '_'), '', $segment)) . '</a>';
}
?>
</div>
```

And create the dividers with CSS. That way you don't have to do some tricky checks in the PHP code:

```
.breadcrumb > a + a:before {
    color: #CCC;
    content: "/ ";
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: Dude, you just save me a lot of nerves and many rows of unnecessary code! This totaly does it much more efficient way. Thank you!

p.s.: No, i'm not using bootstrap! I'm still just learning PHP and Codeigniter

Comment: Glad I could help. I edited the code with the @scrowler recommendation.

Comment: And i will check bootstrap when i'm finnished with that project! ;)
tnx again!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, I don't know exactly what your ".divider1" does, but consider to use the CSS approach, I think it's cleaner.

Comment: It's a arrow for breadcrumb boxes a.k.a. divider :)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kpc6tn1fuiflad/Untitled.png

Comment: So, if I'm guessing right, you are using an empty div with a background-image. The bootstrap approach still applies. As a matter of fact, you can draw the triangle with just CSS: [CSS3 Shapes](http://www.css3shapes.com/). Well, I'm getting too dense with this, enough.

Comment: u have amused me with bootstrap totaly :) Today i was checking all the possibilities he has and i'm totaly using it in my next project!